# Writing to a text file in seperate lines

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a program, which at the end of all the inputs, I write to a text file and it comes up as one big line. Other than going into my text file and manually changing it to multiple lines, how do you write to a python text file in separate lines?

---

**Eta:**

Line one that holds one piece of inputted information

Line two that holds another piece of inputted information

Line three that holds a final piece of inputted information

---

I've tried writing twice to a file before closing it, but it returns an error saying it expected 1 argument and received more.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You should post at least a failed attempt that we can fix; but, due to the simplistic nature of the problem, I'll just give a quick answer anyway.*

Steps:

- Open the file in write (`'w'`) mode (*note that this blanks the file*)
- Write a line
- Write a new-line (`'\n'`). *Note that this step can be combined with the previous*
- Repeat steps 2 and 3 for all your lines
- Close the file.

---

So, here's an implementation of the above. Note how we can use a `with` statement to do the first and last steps in one (and other benefits).

```
lines = ['Line one', 'Line two', 'Line three']
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for l in lines:
         f.write(l + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if i ask a question in the future I will remember to include an example of a failed attempt.